# Is a domed plane possible?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, extrude

So I'm trying to create a new icon, and I've managed to use curves to successfully create the object in a 2D sense, but I want to be able to give it a domed appearance. I know I could extrude and bevel, but the sides will be pushed out and it will make the image seem like its a marshmallow. If I extrude and scale, the separate parts of the plane will scale based off of the cursors location. Heres a screenshot of the plane:

[image]

I want this face to be domed. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you post a blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? I'll try to make it.

Comment: Depends on the topology. Care to upload, as LukeD suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it may be tricky to get a stack of modifiers that will work well for you modifiers. Here's an example with a simple target shape made with 2D Bezier curves getting warped in 3D space by a Lattice modifier:

[image: 3D warp of 2D bezier]

The mesh created by the bezier object isn't going to play will with deformations, but the *Remesh* modifier will. But that won't work on something flat, so you need to use *Solidify* first. Give it a small thickness if you want the end result to still seem flat.

Depending on your shape, *Remesh* may need a larger Octree Depth, and sharpness tweaking.

Next, to fix the smooth shading around the edges, I added an *EdgeSplit* - the default options should work well.

Finally, the deform is done with a *Lattice*. If you aren't familiar with using a Lattice to deform objects, these are a little out of date, but still accurate: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Modifiers/Lattice/Shaping_a_Fork

If you don't need the level of control the Lattice gives you, you could also try the *Cast* modifier (with an Empty as the center of the virtual sphere it is being cast to):
[image]